# I Have A Registration Form That Is Kicking Back Custom Made Errors Before Submission

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm working on a registration for my classifieds (via a tutorial) but I'm having problems. For some reason, just visiting this page: http://classifieds.your-adrenaline-fix.com/register.php
will generate the 2 custom errors you'll see in a red box above the registration form BUT the form hasn't even been submitted yet so I don't know why this is happening. If anyone could shed some light on this I'd be most appreciative and I thank you all in advance!!

(I've been staring at it for hours)

Here's the code that validates and submits the form data;

```
<?php
    if(empty($_POST) === false) {
        $VisitorsFirstName = $_POST['First_Name'];
        $VisitorsLastName = $_POST['Last_Name'];
        $VisitorsEmail = $_POST['E_mail'];
        $VisitorsPassword = $_POST['Pass'];
        $RequiredFlds = array('First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'E_mail', 'Pass', 'PassAgain');

        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
            if(empty($value) && in_array($key, $RequiredFlds) === true) {
                $Err[] = 'All Fields Are Required';
                break 1;
            }
        }

        if(empty($Err) === true) {
            if(email_exists($VisitorsEmail) === true) {
                $Err[] = 'The Email Address \''. $VisitorsEmail. '\' Is Already In Use.';           
            }
            if(strlen($VisitorsPassword) < 4) {
                $Err[] = 'Please Select A Password of At Least 4 Characters.';
            }
            if($_POST['Pass'] !== $_POST['PassAgain']) {
                $Err[] = 'Passwords Do Not Match.';
            }
            if(filter_var($VisitorsEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                $Err[] = 'A Valid Email Address is Required';
            }
        }
    }

    if(isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
        echo 'You Have Now Been Registered and Can Proceed to <a href="add.php">Creating Your First Ad</a><br>(Use the Email and Password That You Registered With to Login)';
    } else {    
    if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($Err) === true) {
        $register_data = array (
            'VisitorsFirstName' => $_POST['First_Name'],
            'VisitorsLastName' => $_POST['Last_Name'],
            'VisitorsPassword' => $_POST['Pass'],
            'VisitorsEmail' => $_POST['E_mail'],
            'Notify' => $_POST['Notify']
            );

            register_func($register_data);
            header('Location: register.php?success');
            exit();

    } else if(empty($Err) === false) {
        echo output_error($Err);
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Try replacing `if(empty($_POST) === false)` with this `if(isset($_POST))` or `if($_POST['something']=='something')`

Comment: Hi @gustyaquino I have tried making changes similar to what you suggested but for reasons unbeknownst to me it's still giving the errors so I put it back

Answer (score 0):

Upon putting just the code you provided on my own server by itself, it works as designed.  It isn't running the top block of code, because the $_POST variable is empty.  Try outputting the contents of $_POST at the top of the file so you can figure out why it isn't empty.

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: Hi @Lawson, Thanks for that tip. I ran as fast as I could to make that change hoping for miracoulous results but I'm still getting the errors. I've tried to even look at this problem from a different angle by considering why the script is displaying these 2 errors for these 2 fields but not the others. Why might that be??

Comment: Well, it's because strlen() of "" is less than 4.  Also, "" is not a valid email address.  The others pass because the passwords ("" and "") are equal, and the email address "" isn't in use.

Comment: Please see my updated answer above, as the issue wasn't the ===.

Comment: Here's the trick.  While a variable ($var) with the string "0" is considered empty, an array with all zero values is not.  You can either check each array value separately, or you can abandon the empty() function.

Comment: Hi @Lawson, I really appreciate your (and everyone's) help. I think I figured out what is causing the problems (after you showed me the print_r($_POST)) Huge Thanks on That!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
if(!empty($_POST['First_Name']) && !empty($_POST['Last_Name']) && !empty($_POST['E_mail']) && !empty($_POST['Pass'])){

....

}

OR

try isset($_POST['First_Name'])......

This works fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

You could instead check if the submit button was pressed. Like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) {
  // get the post values
}
```

This way you could eliminate the script launching before the form was actually submitted. Right now it seems to run as soon as I visit the page.